# Drop text view on center of text

Tags: android

I using Drag and Drop on `TextView`, it work's, but when I drop the `TextView` are not droped on exact x and y of the touch (centering the text view), I know that the `TextView` x and y startof on up-left axis and is because of that my drop don't work as expected... How I can change the `TextView` axis to center or make him center when I drop him?

What it do:
https://gph.is/2yxoPv9

My code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnLongClickListener, View.OnDragListener {

    private val TAG = MainActivity::class.java.getSimpleName()
    private var llPinkLayout: RelativeLayout? = null
    private var tvDragView: TextView? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setUpViews();
        setListeners();
    }

    private fun setListeners() {
        tvDragView?.setOnLongClickListener(this)
        llPinkLayout?.setOnDragListener(this)
    }

    private fun setUpViews() {
        llPinkLayout = findViewById<View>(R.id.ll_pinklayout) as RelativeLayout
        tvDragView = findViewById<View>(R.id.tv_dropdrop) as TextView
    }

    override fun onDrag(view: View, dragEvent: DragEvent): Boolean {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDrag: view->$view\n DragEvent$dragEvent")
        when (dragEvent.action) {
            DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "onDrag: ACTION_DRAG_ENDED ")
                return true
            }
            DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "onDrag: ACTION_DRAG_EXITED")
                return true
            }
            DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "onDrag: ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED")
                return true
            }
            DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "onDrag: ACTION_DRAG_STARTED")
                return true
            }
            DragEvent.ACTION_DROP -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "onDrag: ACTION_DROP")
                val tvState = dragEvent.localState as View
                Log.d(TAG, "onDrag:viewX" + dragEvent.x + "viewY" + dragEvent.y)
                Log.d(TAG, "onDrag: Owner->" + tvState.parent)
                val tvParent = tvState.parent as ViewGroup
                tvParent.removeView(tvState)
                val container = view as RelativeLayout
                container.addView(tvState)
                val contariner = view
                tvParent.removeView(tvState)
                tvState.x = dragEvent.x //the problem are there!
                tvState.y = dragEvent.y //the problem are there!
                view.addView(tvState)
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
                return true
            }
            DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "onDrag: ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION")
                return true
            }
            else -> return false
        }
    }

    override fun onLongClick(v: View?): Boolean {
        val dragShadowBuilder = View.DragShadowBuilder(v)
        v?.startDrag(null, dragShadowBuilder, v, 0)
        return true
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this changing the x and y lines for that:

```
DragEvent.ACTION_DROP -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "onDrag: ACTION_DROP")
                val tvState = dragEvent.localState as View
                Log.d(TAG, "onDrag:viewX" + dragEvent.x + "viewY" + dragEvent.y)
                Log.d(TAG, "onDrag: Owner->" + tvState.parent)
                val tvParent = tvState.parent as ViewGroup
                tvParent.removeView(tvState)
                val container = view as RelativeLayout
                container.addView(tvState)
                val contariner = view
                tvParent.removeView(tvState)
                tvState.x = dragEvent.x - tvState.width/2  // FIXED
                tvState.y = dragEvent.y - tvState.height/2 // FIXED
                view.addView(tvState)
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
                return true
            }
```

I set the TextView x by the `(touch x position) - (TextView width)/2`

I set the TextView y by the `(touch y position) - (TextView height)/2`

With that I can center the `TextView` on exact touch position!